# do relation between $dx$ $dy$ implies existence of a $x$ $y$ relation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

hellow, do $f(dx,dy)=0$ implies existence of $g(x,y)=0$?
lets say i want to solve: $m(x)dx=n(y)dy$ how do i know that $x$ is related to $y$ and they are not independent? do independent argument even exist if $y(x)$ implies $x(y)$? please point me some direction to read on or so...

Comment: If x and y are not related, the integrals are not related.

Comment: @herbsteinberg what integrals?

Comment: Think about the most general possible $f$ given $dx^2=dxdy=dy^2=0$.

Comment: @test $dx$ etc. normally are used in$\int f(x)dx$.  By itself it is not usually meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adjective "independent" in this context is fuzzy and hopefully cannot be made more "crisp", contrasting with probability theory where "independence" has a non-ambiguous definition.

Moreover, there is a real difficulty/ambiguity pertaining at the difference for example between $y$ as a variable and $y$ as a function of another variable such as $x$.

This ambiguity can be traced back to the origin of the differential calculus "à la Leibniz", but at the same time it gives its "full flavour" to calculus I would say, and also its formidable power.

In the present case, here is an interpretation:

$$m(x)dx=n(y)dy \ \ \iff \ \ m(x)dx = n(y) \dfrac{dy}{dx} dx$$

$$\int_0^X m(x)dx = \int_0^Y n(y) \dfrac{dy}{dx} dx$$

(initial bound $0$ has been chosen arbitrarily).

Let $M, N$ be primitive functions of $m$ and $n$ respectively.

$$M(X)-M(0) = N(Y)-N(0)+K \ \ \ (K = \text{constant})\tag{1}$$

showing the kind of relationship that can exist between the two variables. For example is $m(x)=x$ and $n(y)=y$, (1) becomes:

$$\frac12 X^2=\frac12 Y^2+K$$

otherwise said:

$$\frac12 x^2=\frac12 y^2+K$$

Indeed $x$ and $y$ are not independent !

Comment: thank you for your answer!, i will no accept it for now because i dont know how this site works and if other people could responde then. also what happens if $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ ?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ **for all $x$** is a particular case. The computation isn't modified but indeed it means $y=constant$ therefore there is no dependence of $y$ with respect to $x$ in this special case.